# Should I execute a function multiple times or use an array to loop through?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, google-tag-manager

I have a bit of code to replace text in an existing website via Google Tag Manager.

I first find the parent element, and then the child elements to replace the text. Like this:

```
doReplacement(".parent-element", ".first-child", ".second-child", "Text to be replaced", "Replacement text");
```

Is it better to do multiple runs of doReplacement with different values each time, or is it better to create an array to loop through? Which is faster?

Comment: The performance hit in your example will not come from function vs. loop (does not matter which, really) but from potentially forcing repaints/reflows on your page every time you change the text.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need extreme performance optimization I suggest that you use loop anyway. Note that foreach is slower than for/while, but in the end, this depends on where it will be executed of course.

Still, it is better to use loops for flexibility of you code.